# Azure Data Factory - Lookup activity - How to access error data? (SQL error)

Tags: logging, error-handling, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am using **Azure Data Factory** and **Azure Database Instance**.

I have a Data Factory Lookup activity that calls a procedure that can fail. In the `CATCH` block `THROW` is called when a failure occurs. I can see the 'output' of `THROW` when inspecting the error popup in the Azure Data Factory client. I am currently unable to access this 'output', **it is not output as far as I can tell**.

**I have tried (each line is an attempt):**

```
@activity('activityName').output.firstRow.error

@activity('activityName').output.firstRow.errors

@activity('activityName').error.message

@activity('activityName').errors.message

@activity('activityName').errors.number

@activity('activityName').ErrorCode

@activity('activityName').Errors
```

**When inspecting the error popup:**

> Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,
> 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
> Message=A database operation failed with the following error:
> 'blabla',     Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,
> Message=blabla, Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,
> SqlErrorNumber=245, Class=16, ErrorCode=-2146232060, State=1,
> Errors=[{ Class=16, Number=245,State=1,Message=blabla,},],'

**The data is clearly there**, just I cannot access it and I am finding the documentation lacking in this case. There is comprehensive documentation on accessing the error output from a CopyActivity but not LookupActivity.

What I am trying to achieve is logging errors. In some cases, the procedure succeeds and needs to submit output to Data Factory which is why I must capture the error data from the `THROW`; I have been unable to fail this task by raising the error again with `THROW` after returning a `SELECT` to Data factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can access an activities complex output as below:

```
@activity('*activityName*').output.*subfield1*.*subfield2*
```

the error body is in the below format:

```
"value": {
        "errorCode": "2100",
        "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Invalid object name 'SalesLT.Customr'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Invalid object name 'SalesLT.Customr'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=208,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=208,State=1,Message=Invalid object name 'SalesLT.Customr'.,},],'",
        "failureType": "UserError",
        "target": "Lookup",
        "details": []
    }
```

You can use this in add dynamic content:

```
@activity('<name of your lookup>').Error.message
```

Here is an example, where you can use **Add activity on** method to select the output stream that continues onto the next activity.

[image]

A stored procedure results an error:

[image]

[image]

The string variable **errorOutput** now holds the error message!

[image]

Further, you can access each element of error message by using dot operator.

```
 1. @activity('<name of your lookup>').Error.errorCode
    
 2. @activity('<name of your lookup>').Error.failureType

 3. @activity('<name of your lookup>').Error.target

 4. @activity('<name of your lookup>').Error.details
```

**Alternately,** if you want to ensure an activity is executed only when its previous activity (lookup activity in your scenario) was successful, you can also use **If condition** activity on "**Completion**" stream.

[image]

Different causes may lead to this error. Check the [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-guide#error-code-sqloperationfailed) for possible cause analysis and related recommendation.